# Compare two strings and check if a common string can be built by deleting characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

I am trying to solve ASCII distance problem for any given two strings. I have written the code to check for unmatched characters between two strings and calculated partial ascii distance. But I still need to compare two strings ( eg. as below. ) and come up with a common string that can be built out of those strings. Here is the example as below.

```
Let's say s1="elete" s2="leet"

Expected Output:
"let"
```

How can I identify the extra characters from both strings and come up with a common string in case of above example?

My code looks like this as below and what it does is compare two strings and calculate ASCII score for unmatched characters between two strings.

Code:

```
class Solution {
    public int minimumDeleteSum(String s1, String s2) {

        int sum = 0;

        char[] cstr1 = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] cstr2 = s2.toCharArray();

        String res = compareCharacters( cstr1,cstr2 );

        sum += Integer.parseInt( res.split(",")[1] );
        String news1 = res.split(",")[0];

        res = compareCharacters( cstr2,cstr1 );        
        sum += Integer.parseInt( res.split(",")[1] );
        String news2 = res.split(",")[0];

        /*Would like to add the code here to get all characters that are not allowing to build a common string and get their ASCII values.How do I approach this problem? */

        return sum;
    }

    public String compareCharacters( char[] cstr1, char[] cstr2 ){

        int ascii_score = 0;
        int flag = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for( int i=0;i<cstr1.length;i++ ){
            flag = 0;
            for( int j=0;j<cstr2.length;j++ ){
            if( cstr1[i] == cstr2[j] )  
                flag++;
            }
            if( flag == 0 ){
                ascii_score += (int)cstr1[i];
                cstr1[i] = '\0';
            }
            if( flag>0 )
                sb.append(cstr1[i]);                
        }          

        return sb.toString()+','+Integer.toString(ascii_score);
    }

}
```

Please let me know if any questions. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Look for LCS (the longest common subsequence) algorithms

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334221/1139196. I altered the code slightly to match with your question.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LongestCommonSubstring {
    public static char[] lcs(List l1, List l2) {
        int[][] d = new int[l1.size() + 1][l2.size() + 1];
        for (int i1 = 1; i1 <= l1.size(); i1++) {
            for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= l2.size(); i2++) {
                if (l1.get(i1 - 1).equals(l2.get(i2 - 1))) {
                    d[i1][i2] = d[i1 - 1][i2 - 1] + 1;
                } else {
                    d[i1][i2] = Math.max(d[i1 - 1][i2], d[i1][i2 - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        int i1 = l1.size(), i2 = l2.size();
        char[] result = new char[d[i1][i2]];
        while (i1 > 0 && i2 > 0) {
            if (l1.get(i1 - 1).equals(l2.get(i2 - 1))) {
                result[d[i1][i2] - 1] = ((String) l1.get(i1 - 1)).charAt(0);
                i1 -= 1;
                i2 -= 1;
            } else if (d[i1][i2] == d[i1 - 1][i2]) {
                i1 -= 1;
            } else {
                i2 -= 1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l1 = Arrays.asList("elete".split(""));
        List l2 = Arrays.asList("leet".split(""));
        System.out.println(new String(lcs(l1, l2)));
    }
}
```